# Persistence of data in Logger

Tags: google-apps-script, rhino, google-apps-script-editor

How long does data stay in Logger.log before it is flushed? What is the persistence time of data in Logger.log?

I have a number of scripts that feed data into Logger which is then emailed to me.  I would like the log file sent once a day with all my script results rather than individually as each script runs.

NOTE:

Comment: I would recommend that you log you data into a file of your own.

Comment: Logger.log refreshes at execution. Logging to your own sheet is the way to go.

Comment: [Stackdriver Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) is available as a free/basic tier service. Use [Console Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console) with apps scripts for writing to Stackdriver Logging - [Stackdriver Logging Docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/)

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Exactly the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian said, the log file is written over every time the script runs. That is, the output of `Logger.log` will persist until the script runs again.