# Google Web App doesnt log anything on the development script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm learning how to use Google Web App and I wrote the following Hello World to test it out:

Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
    Logger.log("hello world 1");
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("interface");
}

function submit() {
    console.log(12);
}
```

interface.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>formDemo.html</title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8" />
        <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Google Sheets Interface</h1>
        <button id="btn">Submit</button>
    </body>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", buttonPress);
        function buttonPress() {
            console.log("hello world 2");
            google.script.run.submit();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

However, `Logger.log(12)` and the `Logger.log("Hello world 1")` don't seem to do anything at all. I know they are spelled correctly because when I run them directly from the IDE, the functions work, and when I go to **View > Executions**, it says the web app did run the functions. I am at a loss here, I looked up on google however I haven't found anyone with my exact problem.

Comment: Related [Persistence of data in Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46793837/1595451), [Logger log cleared automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48176433/1595451)

Comment: Try view>stackdriver logging( switch gcp, if you need to)

Comment: Thank you both, I didnt know that was how the Log worked.

Comment: @SantiagoS Consider adding a answer. See [answer]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No logs are created in Stackdriver logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010980/no-logs-are-created-in-stackdriver-logging)