# No logs are created in Stackdriver logging

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

In my google app script, I have:

```
Logger.log("test");
```

and I even tried

```
console.log("test");
```

But neither is printed to the stackdriver log, even after I've set the project id to a Google Cloud Project id.

The screen shows:

[image]

Comment: Did you, by chance, click the "Read about logging" button?

Comment: Nothing relevant to Google Apps Script there

Comment: Take a look at view executions.  You can find both the Logger and console in there.

Comment: As Ruben said, stackdriver logs are not enabled by default. To enable them you have to follow said GCP project assign procedure. Logs in app script dashboard, however, are always there.

Comment: @Cooper I went into executions, where is the console and logger?

Answer (score 2):

To being able to see the logs on Stackdriver your project should have linked to a Google Cloud Standard project instad of the default project otherwise you only could see the "Stackdriver logs" on the executions pages in https://script.google.com

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#using_stackdriver_logging

> #### Using Stackdriver Logging
>
> Stackdriver logs are attached to the GCP project associated with your
> Apps Script. You can view a simplified version of these logs in the
> Apps Script dashboard. To make full use of Stackdriver Logging and its
> capabilities, use a standard GCP project with your script project.
> This lets you access Stackdriver logs directly in the GCP Console and
> gives you more viewing and filtering options.